# jQuery animate movement left and right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Using jquery's `.css()` i am changing the left attributes value to move a div left or right. Im looking for a way to animate this change as it occurs.  Nothing ive tried is working, ive tried jQueryUI's `.show(slide)` function, but this moves the whole div, rather than just the 120px movement i need.

This is my current function which is working without an animation:

```
$('#plrt').live("click",function(){
    var lm=$('.plwid').css("left");
    lm = (parseInt(lm) + 120);
    $('.plwid').css("left", lm);    
});
```

this is the slide function, it does not work properly as the whole div goes from `display:hide` to `display:show`, rather than just moving the pixel change

Comment: Have you tried using animate?

Comment: @dqlopez. You need `http://` in the link so it would work...

Comment: show us some [demo](http://jsfiddle.net), or as suggested by @Jrod [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `animate()`

```
$('#plrt').on("click",function(){
    $('.plwid').animate({ left: '+=120' }, 400 );
});
```

Comment: @dqlopez I was just using the OP's code, but good point - updated

Comment: @dqlopez thats my bad using the `.live`, bad habit from using it before 1.7 @zoltan, thank you sir, this worked like a charm

Answer (score 5):

I have whipped up a quick example of what I think you are trying to achieve.
You should check out [jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```js
//note live is deprecated
$('#plrt').on("click", function() {
  //perform custom animation to add 120px to current left CSS position
  $('.plwid').animate({
    left: '+=120'
  });
});
```

```css
#plrt{
  position:relative;
  background:red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.plwid{
  position:absolute;
  background:blue;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="plrt"></div>
<div class="plwid"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$('#plrt').on('click', function() { 
    $('.plwid').animate({ left: '+=120', 5000 });     
});
```